# Laravel. How to reverse `php artisan breeze:install`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-breeze

I have ran `php artisan breeze:install` but I want to reverse it so I can install vue: `php artisan breeze:install vue`.

How to reverse the `php artisan breeze:install` command.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the vendor folder
2. Remove the breeze from the composer.json
3. Then composer install

Comment: Also keep in mind that as the command "php artisan breeze:install" is equivalent to "php artisan breeze:install blade" it means that you will have to delete the .blade files added by the command inside the [resource] folder

Comment: step 3 should be getting rid of the service provider if it's there: sed -i '/Laravel\\Breeze\\BreezeServiceProvider::class/d' config/app.php

Answer (score 2):

1. `composer remove laravel/breeze`
2. `composer update`
3. `php artisan config:cache`

To ensure that it's been uninstalled, open your **composer.json** file and see if laravel/breeze is no longer listed in **require-dev**.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the blade files that are created and running the install command again should do the job, maybe some of the controllers have to be removed too.

Edit:
Removing breeze from the composer dependecies won’t help as you are trying to install it with vue

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Vendor folder in your directory.
2. Delete the Vendor folder.
3. Remove the dependency from composer.json file
4. Reinstall the Laravel Breeze package.

Answer (score 0):

If `git` is used in the project, it will be easy to revert.

1. Revert the commit
2. Run `composer install`
3. Run `npm install`

It can be reverted without `git` as well.

1. Figure out which files are created or modified by `breeze` installation, then delele those manually. Normally the following files and folders are created or modified. And revert the changes of the modified files (althought it's very complicated).

```
    created: app/Http/Controllers/Auth/
    created: app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController.php
    created: app/Http/Requests/
    created: app/View/
    created: package-lock.json
    created: postcss.config.js
    created: resources/views/auth/
    created: resources/views/components/
    created: resources/views/dashboard.blade.php
    created: resources/views/layouts/
    created: resources/views/profile/
    created: routes/auth.php
    created: tailwind.config.js
    created: tests/Feature/Auth/
    created: tests/Feature/ProfileTest.php
    created: tests/Pest.php

    modified: app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
    modified: composer.json
    modified: composer.lock
    modified: package.json
    modified: resources/css/app.css
    modified: resources/js/app.js
    modified: resources/views/welcome.blade.php
    modified: routes/web.php
    modified: tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php
    modified: tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php
    modified: vite.config.js
```

2. Run `composer remove laravel/breeze`
3. Run `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

You would just scroll down to the folder "vendor\laravel" and delete the laravel folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).